# How to call javascript after file upload via kendo.upload and Form in MVC?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-upload

I'm trying to submit a form where one of it's properties is List of files.

After the **ActionResult** has completed successfully i need to show a success message that has to be triggered via **Javascript**.

If i use **Ajax.Begin** form the javascript message is shown, but the files are not sent to the **ActionResult**, on the other hand if I use **Html.BeginForm** the files are sent, but I'm not able to call the javascript function and therefore I'm not able to trigger my success message.

here is my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, 
        new { id = "exceptionForm", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
   @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Notes)
   @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
   .Name("EventFiles")
   )
   <div >
      <button href="#">
      submit
      </button>
   </div>
}
```

My Action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Action(Model model)
{
   //do something
   result = new BaseJsonData();
   result.HasCompletedSuccessfully = true;
   return this.Json(result);
}
```

My model

```
public class EventModel
{
   public string Notes { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> EventFiles { get; set; }
}
```

My javascript:

```
onSuccess: function (data) {
     if (data.HasCompletedSuccessfully) {
      //show message extention
     }
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Schewns

Comment: try adding an event in the declaration @(Html.Kendo().Upload().Name('EventFiles')).Events("onComplete") and create a function for onComplete in javascript which will be called once the upload is complete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging and trying some approaches I went for this solution:

I downloaded this plugin:

http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#download

After installation, I added this javascript function:

```
$('#exceptionForm').ajaxForm({
  complete: function (response) {
    var data = response.responseJSON;
    if (data.HasCompletedSuccessfully) {
            //warning message
    }
})
```

And it worked like a charm.
Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to directly use the asynchronous mode of the Telerik control:

.CSHTML

```
@(Html.Kendo().Upload()
            .Name("files")
            .Async(a => a
                .Save("Save", "Upload")
                .Remove("Remove", "Upload")
                .AutoUpload(true)
            )
            .Events(events => events
                .Success("onSuccess")
                .Error("onError")
            )
        )
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
    function onSuccess(e) {
        alert("Success (" + e.operation + ")");
    }

    function onError(e) {
        alert("Error (" + e.operation + ")");
    }      
</script>
```

More information is available in the Telerik docs:

- [Asynchronous Mode](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/upload/modes#asynchronous-mode)
- [Upload Async](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/upload/async)
- [Upload Events](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/upload/events)

Comment: the thing is i just want to submit my form after i hit submit, like that it will submit every time i upload a form :) i will post the answer now, I got it